# Any issue with splicing a 220 line?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I have an existing 220 line (10-2 wire), that is an outlet for a dust collector.

I need to move the dust collector about 5 more feet down the wall. So the outlet needs to move 5 feet too.

Any problem with taking the plug out of the metal box, using it as a junction box instead, and splicing in another 5 feet of #10 wire to a new outlet down the wall?

I know this is fine with 110 but I don't do much with 220 ever, so just making sure.

Answer (score 2):

No problem, that is how you would do it. The only thing you cannot do is to make a splice in a wall and cover it without access to it.

#8 wire sliced onto #10 though might be a problem, not at the splice end, but is your receptacle rated to terminate #8 wire? Why are you increasing the wire size?

Comment: I'm not changing wire size. I simply mis-typed. Thank you for confirming!